# reload command always returning could not reload in fs discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js, fs

I've coded a reload command for my discord bot.
it runs bot the bot is always giving me my error message that it could not reload the command.
does anyone see stuff wrong with the code?

```
module.exports.run = async (Client, msg, args) => {

    let commandName = args[0].toLowerCase()

    if(msg.author.id != "393165866285662208" ) return msg.channel.send('Youre not drizzy, idiot')

    if(!args[0]) return msg.channel.send('Provide a command to reload')

    try {
        delete require.cache[require.resolve(`./${commandname}.js`)]
        Client.commands.delete(commandName)
        const pull = require(`./${commandName}.js`)
        Client.commands.set(commandName, pull)
    } catch(e) {
        return msg.channel.send(`Could not reload: \`${args[0].toUpperCase()}\``)
    }

    msg.channel.send(`\`${commandName}\` was reloaded!`)

}
```

Comment: What does the actual error say? `console.error(e)`

Comment: it dont say anything

Comment: the code is running but it doesnt reload the file

Comment: The error will tell you what's going on but you need to log it to read it. In your `catch` block, add `console.error(e)` as the first line and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58175085/edit) your question to show the output.